# Using equation as part of view creation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

When i try this i get a syntax error but not sure if its my approach that might be wrong. I'm trying to add a flag to a table to identify certain records

```
Create view
as
SELECT
col1 * 0.5 / col2 as value_per_sqm,
col3 / col2 as other_value,
(col1 * 0.5 / col2) < (col3 / col2) as higher
```

Which returns;
 `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("`

Adjusting the above i can see that i can run a boolean and get back true if i use no equation and the first two equations work. I tried;

```
Create view
as
SELECT
col1 * 0.5 / col2 as value_per_sqm,
col3 / col2 as other_value,
(value_per_sqm) < other_value) as higher
```

But it can't query the column as it's not created.

Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Just put the first two (value_per_sqm and other_value) in a sub-query and then select all three from the sub-query.  BTW you need some commas!

Comment: Thank you, just going to figure out how to do the subquery, commas were there and now in the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you on your way:

```
create view yourview
as
SELECT value_per_sqm, 
       other_value,
       (value_per_sqm < other_value) as higher
FROM 
(SELECT col1 * 0.5 / col2 as value_per_sqm,
col3 / col2 as other_value FROM yourtable) subQ;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. is there a more elegant way if (on this example) i want to select all from table 1 and then run the equations ie `select all from (select all from table1) subq1, (select my_calc as calc from table1 )subq2`?

Comment: In this case select * from table1, (select mycalc from table2) subQ should be sufficient.  This will be pretty efficient so long as subQ is giving you some sort of aggregate.  Otherwise you need to join table1 to subQ in some way to prevent a Cartesian join.  Without seeing the exact details of what you want to do, it is very hard to say.